# mysql two queries

Tags: php, mysql

i have a commenting system;
I have one query

```
SELECT ShoutID,Message, User, Date, ShoutImageThumb, ShoutImageBig,UserID, 
       Email, FullName, UserImageThumb, Admin FROM shoutbox LEFT JOIN users ON 
       users.Email = shoutbox.User ORDER BY ShoutID DESC LIMIT 10
```

and while its going through the loop on the page 
i run another query in the loop to get the comments for that message

```
SELECT users.UserID, users.Email, users.FullName, shoutboxcomments.ShoutID, 
       shoutboxcomments.`Comment`, shoutboxcomments.`Date`, 
       shoutboxcomments.`User`, shoutboxcomments.CommentID FROM shoutboxcomments 
       LEFT JOIN users ON users.Email = shoutboxcomments.User 
       WHERE ShoutID = '.$ShoutID.' ORDER BY CommentID ASC
```

is it possible to join these queries or how i can streamline it , as im building in php using mvc architecture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of running one query per post, use `IN` to get the comments for multiple posts at once.

```
SELECT users.UserID, users.Email, ...
FROM shoutboxcomments
LEFT JOIN users
ON users.Email = shoutboxcomments.User
WHERE ShoutID IN (1, 4, 15, 22)
ORDER BY CommentID
```

Comment: Hi mark , thanks for the speedy reponse, i dont understand fully though. you creat two queries, and in the while loop you only call the results of the second query(comments) ?

Comment: You have two queries, A and B. First send query A to the database. This returns a list of ids (and some other data). Use the list of IDs to build query B, then send that query and get the results. So in total you send only two queries. At no point should you need to execute a query in loop. You only need loops to fetch the results.